# Solving a binomial when one of the terms is in the form $e^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

Say I have the function $y=4e^{-2x}-3x$. I can use a graphing calculator to approximately determine the roots, but how do I find an exact answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exact answer is only possible in terms of the Lambert $W$ function ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)):
$$\begin{align*}
0 &= 4e^{-2x}-3x\\\\
3x &= 4e^{-2x}\\\\
2xe^{2x}&=\tfrac{8}{3}\\\\
ye^y&=\tfrac{8}{3}\;\;(y=2x)\\\\
y&=W(\tfrac{8}{3})\\\\
x&=\tfrac{1}{2} W(\tfrac{8}{3})
\end{align*}$$